# error in smart contract indicate haven't unique attribute.

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I tried to write a smart contract which is able to complaining. Here is the code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Complain {
    //Model Complain
    struct compalins {
        uint id;
        string category;
        string desc;
        string complainer;
    }

    mapping( uint => complains) public newComplain;

    uint public complainCount;

    function Complain () public {
        addComplain("c1","bhbh","bybhb");
        addComplain("c2","bhbh","bybhb");
    }

    function addComplain (string _category,string desc,string complainer){
        complainCount ++;
       // newComplain[ComplainCount] = complains(complainCount,_category,desc,complainer);
    }
}
```

in this mapping function gives an error and say structure of the complains haven't Unique value. But id is Unique.

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled "complains" when you declared your struct. (You spelled it "compalins" there.) So the error on the `mapping` line is that there's no such identifier "complains". If you fix the typo, the code will compile.